# How to position AdSense on site with CSS position: absolute

Tags: css, position, ads, adsense

I have an AdSense account, and simply copy/pasted a block of Javascript to include ads on my site.  However, since I did not put any HTML in place, the Js is generating an iframe and an ins element which the ads are appearing within.

I want to move those ads to the left of my content, where I have made space for them.  I've tried adding CSS like "ins, iframe { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }" but it seems to be overwritten.

So my question is: how can I force the AdSense ads to appear where I want them to?  Preferably with CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it the same way you use CSS to control anything else: put it in a div, give it a class (or id), and format the parent object.

Are you already using CSS? If so, just add a new one something like this in `main.css`:

```
#google{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:160px;
    top:120px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then in your page, where appropriate, add the following around Google's JavaScript:

```
<div id="google">
    <--! code here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Ugh, I didn't think it would insert its HTML within the location I dropped the Javascript, so I was dropping it in the head, making it impossible to style.  Thank you!

Comment: missing the character # in css